# Generic method for logging

Tags: java, generics, java-8, predicate

I want to create a generic method for logging which can take any type and log depending on a `Predicate`.

This is the log method (I put them in a `map` for handling later):

```
private void logIf(Predicate<T> p, T t, PersonId id, String message) {
    if (p.test(t)) {
        logMap.put(id, message);
    }
}
```

I am trying to use it as follows (We have our own Date class called `DatumA`):

```
logIf(d -> d.nollKoll(), o1.getEndDate(), id, "Datum contains year, month or day with value 0.");
```

..where `o1.getEndDate()` returns a `DatumA` object which has the method `nollKoll()` which returns a `boolean`.

The compiler complains:

```
The method logIf(Predicate<T>, T, PersonId, String) in the type
SkapaKundMasterData<T> is not applicable for the arguments
(Predicate<T>, DatumA, PersonId, String)
```

How could I make this work?

Comment: Can the type of `d -> d.nollKoll()` be `Predicate<DatumA>`?

Comment: @Eran I want to be able to work with any type. Is it possible?

Comment: Which class does the `nollKoll()` method belong to? Does it belong to `DatumA`?

Comment: @Eran yes in `DatumA` but not necessarily. I can move it if it helps.

Comment: Where is T declared?

Comment: @Eran In the class where the `logIf` method is. And I call it there too

Comment: What happens if you change `d -> d.nollKoll()` to `(DatumA d) -> d.nollKoll()`?

Comment: `Incompatible type specified for lambda expression's parameter d` and `.. is not applicable for the arguments ((DatumA d) -> {}, DatumA, PersonId, String)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `logIf` method is `private`, you must be calling it from within the same class (`SkapaKundMasterData`).

However, within the `SkapaKundMasterData` class, `T` can be anything (depending on how you instantiate a specific `SkapaKundMasterData` instance). Therefore you can't pass a `DatumA` instance where `T` is expected.

Suppose, for example, you create an instance of:

```
SkapaKundMasterData<String> instance = new SkapaKundMasterData<>();
```

In that case, `logIf(Predicate<T>, T, PersonId, String)` would require arguments of the types `Predicate<String>`, `String`, `PersonId` and `String`, but you are passing a `Predicate<DatumA>` and a `DatumA`.

If you want the method to work, consider moving the type parameter to the method (or adding a new type parameter if you still need the `T` parameter at the class level).

For example:

```
private <S> void logIf(Predicate<S> p, S t, PersonId id, String message) {
    if (p.test(t)) {
        logMap.put(id, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hallelujah! moving the type parameter did it. Seems obvious now. Thanks a bunch!